# What is the correct way to re-use UILabel's style?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have several `UILabel`s which have same visual treatment. Instead of redefining every single property every time, I am thinking of just making copies of an instance and changing the text. Is this how it should be done?

Another way is to create a factory method, but I'm not that fond of the idea.

Comment: method/function/MACRO: you're pick - when i'm creating them in InterfaceBuilder i definitely duplicate them, but i wouldn't want to do it in code (never been a "prototype" fan) - but i mostly avoid creating UILabels in code.

Comment: addendum: i have subclasses of `UITableViewCell` that modify their contained `UITextField`s on half a dozen fronts (when changing into/out of editing mode) - copy doesn't cut it there,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're willing to learn Three20, you could use the `TTLabel` class, which is incorporated with Three20's stylesheet system, which is basically designed to solve your problem.  However, I personally have had trouble parsing Three20's so-called documentation, so I think learning to use this library just to solve your problem is a lot of overhead.

My work-around for this problem is to put together a mini factory method, like this:

```
// Example:
- (UILabel *)makeLabel {
  UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
  label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kMyFontSize];
  label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
  [self.view addSubview:label];
  return label;
}
```

Then when I use this method, other code gets cleaner:

```
UILabel *nameLabel = [self makeLabel];
nameLabel.text = userName;
UILabel *titleLabel = [self makeLabel];
titleLable.text = myTitle;
// Both labels have consistent style.
```

PengOne suggests subclassing UILabel.  That's an option, although I think this factory method does the job just as well with less work.

Comment: PS  If you use code like this, don't forget to set the label's frame somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler. I am curious about Three20. Some people say it's an overkill, but the site says you can pick and choose which module to include.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to subclass `UILabel` so that it defaults to your preferences. It's pretty simple to do. Create a new file in Xcode (and Objective C Class) called `CustomLabel` (or whatever you like).

CustomLabel.m :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomLabel : UILabel {
}

@end
```

CustomLabel.h :

```
#import "CustomLabel.h"

@implementation CustomLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // CUSTOMIZATION HERE
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
} 

@end
```

If this seems like overkill, then you can just create a method in your ViewController to do the customization:

```
-(void)customizeLabel:(UILabel *)label {
    // CUSTOMIZATION HERE
}
```

then call this on any label you create.

Comment: I don't think the amount of styling warrants a subclass. It's really just color/background/font/shadow

Comment: @pixelfreak: If you want to use it more than a couple of times, and want to be able to apply universal changes at a later date, then this is the best way to do it. Otherwise, you'll have to copy and paste the same code each time, which is fine, but this doesn't create much overhead.